# When can I say that it's the best-optimized query?

Tags: mysql

I tried to optimize a query, but it still a tad bit slow. Here, EXPLAIN statement data for reference. Also adding an execution and evaluation cost information JSON. Can you tell me if I can improve something? Or it's the best that I can do.

[Exaplain.json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S8c651Fol0fokPuLT4CF56v26HV6Ethj/view?usp=sharing)

[image: exaplainTable]

**EDIT**

*What I really want to know is, a way to know that the query is fully optimized and I should start looking somewhere else.*

Anyways, please tell me for this query and I will learn something more. Adding the query and a diagram of the [table structure.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZlmlvGKpLYxOPsW8cfEZ-9g2PuWkvN9t/view?usp=sharing)

```
SELECT o.object, b.baseline, s.testType, ut.suite, 
JSON_EXTRACT(ut.failTestsData, '$.failButBaselinePassesTests[*]', 
'$.baselineDataNotAvailableTests[*]', 
'$.failDifferentThanBaselineTests[*]') AS failTests FROM objects as o
LEFT JOIN baselines as b ON b.baselineID = o.baselineID
LEFT JOIN instances AS i ON o.objectID = i.objectID
LEFT JOIN buildOSs as os ON i.osID = os.osID
LEFT JOIN unittestsdetails AS ut ON ut.instanceID = i.instanceID
LEFT JOIN suites AS s ON s.suiteID = ut.suiteID
WHERE o.objectID IN ( 20836, 20210, 20201, 20202, 20370, 21138, 20731, 
22242, 21168, 21476, 23384, 22043, 20548, 20289, 20777, 21324, 20545, 
20682, 20266, 21184, 21202, 20741, 20918, 20261, 20516, 20291, 20619, 
21438, 20351, 22047, 20264, 20265, 21181, 20988, 20842, 21429, 20643, 
20570, 20775, 21904, 20923........... )
```

If you need something else please let me know.

Comment: To be able to improve your query we need to see the query. And without info about the tables and what indexes exists how can we know if the database have chosen the correct indexes? We need a lot more info to be able to help you with this.

Comment: Please add the specific query, the tables definition, including existing indexes.

Answer (score 1):

> a way to know that the query is fully optimized and I should start looking somewhere else

This doesn't really exist, for a simple reason : if your query is a "bit" complex, depending on the data in your table, what is "fully optimized" may turn to be a pretty bad choice.

Working on a single line vs some thousand of thousand is not the same.

For less complex query, I'll say : if every `WHERE` and `JOIN` clause use an index, then you're probably as close as "optimized" you can (maybe function based index and different kind of index, but that's it).

Looking at your query is seem you're already done ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand there are many aspects to the optimization.  From your answer, I can infer that every WHERE or JOIN should use some kind of index. The performance will depend on how useful those indices are.

Comment: @AvinashL "every " is not really true either : if you have a single line in your table, index is useless / may add a bit over-cost. Optimization is a tricky thing, no real absolute true :/ Even your `where in` clause here could be moved to `LEFT JOIN baselines as b ON (b.baselineID = o.baselineID AND o.objectID IN (...) )` depending of the query engine it may improve the runtime.